# Pandas : first datetime field gets automatically converted to timestamp type

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

When creating a pandas dataframe object (python 2.7.9, pandas 0.16.2), the first datetime field gets automatically converted into a pandas timestamp. Why? Is it possible to prevent this so as to keep the field in the original type?

Please see code below:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas
```

create a dict:

```
x = {'cusip': np.array(['10553M10', '67085120', '67085140'], dtype='|S8'), 

     'vstart':np.array([datetime.datetime(2001, 11, 16, 0, 0),
     datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 22, 0, 0)], 
     dtype=object), 

     'vstop': np.array([datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 28, 0, 0), 
     datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 0, 0)], 
     dtype=object), 

     'id': np.array(['EQ0000000000041095', 'EQ0000000000041095', 'EQ0000000000041095'], 
     dtype='|S18')}
```

So, the vstart and vstop keys are datetime so far. However, after:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data = x)
```

the vstart becomes a pandas Timestamp automatically while vstop remains a datetime

```
type(df.vstart[0])
#class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'
type(df.vstop[0])
#type 'datetime.datetime'
```

I don't understand why the first datetime column that the constructor comes across gets converted to Timestamp by pandas. And how to tell pandas to keep the data types as they are. Can you help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually I've noticed something in your data , it has nothing to do with your first or second date column in your column `vstop` there is a datetime with value `dt.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 0, 0)` , if you changed the year on this date to a normal year like `2020` for example both columns will be treated the same .

just note that I'm importing `datetime` module as `dt`

```
x = {'cusip': np.array(['10553M10', '67085120', '67085140'], dtype='|S8'), 
     'vstop': np.array([dt.datetime(2012, 2, 28, 0, 0), dt.datetime(2014, 12, 22, 0, 0), dt.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0)], dtype=object),
     'vstart': np.array([dt.datetime(2001, 11, 16, 0, 0),dt.datetime(2012, 2, 28, 0, 0), dt.datetime(2014, 12, 22, 0, 0)], dtype=object), 
     'id': np.array(['EQ0000000000041095', 'EQ0000000000041095', 'EQ0000000000041095'], dtype='|S18')}

In [27]:
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df
Out[27]:
cusip                   id          vstart  vstop
10553M10    EQ0000000000041095  2001-11-16  2012-02-28
67085120    EQ0000000000041095  2012-02-28  2014-12-22
67085140    EQ0000000000041095  2014-12-22  2020-12-31

In [25]:
type(df.vstart[0])
Out[25]:
pandas.tslib.Timestamp

In [26]:
type(df.vstop[0])
Out[26]:
pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you. this seems to fix the problem.